# How to hide radio buttons in c#

Tags: c#, radio-button, hidden

I want to hide some radio buttons based on a value.
How to do that?

I was trying this.

```
if(ArbeitsplatzId==400)
            {
                //RbAmWartungRbRüstenRbRPMWartungRbSchichtwechsel
                RbAmWartung.Visibility = false;
                RbAmWartung.Visibility = "Hidden";            
            }
```

in xaml code it's wotking with this: `Visibility="Hidden"`

Comment: I think you should use the following  `RbAmWartung.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Try the following:

```
if (ArbeitsplatzId == 400)
{
    RbAmWartung.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

The `Visibilty` property is used here. Learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.visibility?view=windowsdesktop-7.00).

Answer (score -1):

```
if (ArbeitsplatzId >= 400 && ArbeitsplatzId <= 499)
            {
                //btnSap.Visibility = lib.Visibility.Hidden;                               
                RbAmWartung.Visibility = lib.Visibility.Hidden;
                RbRüsten.Visibility = lib.Visibility.Hidden;
                RbRPMWartung.Visibility = lib.Visibility.Hidden;
                RbSchichtwechsel.Visibility = lib.Visibility.Hidden;
            }
```

Comment: Is that your accepted answer or what are you tryring to say?